# Meaningless Choice

Tags: phrases, expressions

What's a name for a meaningless choice? A choice that has no effect on outcome. Something similar to a phrase like "pyrrhic victory".

Comment: You may choose A or B. *No matter choice* (or no matter what choice you make), you will loose her.

Answer (score 1):

*inconsequential*, defined by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inconsequential) as:

> of little or no importance; insignificant; trivial

The OP asked for a choice that had no effect on the outcome.  The outcome could be serious, no matter the choice, as in Graffito's comment.

Example:  Whether you go to Romano's or Chez Louis for dinner is inconsequential; she's decided to take the job in Singapore.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **decision quicksand**.

Quoting [Physcology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/ulterior-motives/201207/getting-stuck-in-trivial-choices)

> ... a paper in the August 2012 issue of the Journal of Consumer Research by Aner Sela and Jonah Berger.
>
> They suggest that unimportant decisions can suck us in when they are more difficult than we expect them to be. They call these choices decision quicksand, because they pull you in and take more effort than they deserve.

See their research paper at [jonahberger.com](http://jonahberger.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Decision_Quicksand.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If a decision is of no practical effect, the word "academic" could be used.

> It is academic now whether Mark proposes to her or not. She has already  made up her mind to marry George.

If the decision will cause different immediate effects, but the end result is the same, the phrase "catch 22" can be used.

> It is Catch 22. If she makes the first move he will think her too forward, and that will put him off. If she leaves it to him to make the first move, he will never get round to it. Either way they won't get together.

If the decision will be made by someone else the phrase "Hobson's Choice" may be used.

> The menus said fish served with vegetables. I asked for carrots, but it was Hobson's choice. That day they were only serving peas.

Answer (score 0):

- Insignificant

  Doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things, alternatively:
- Useless
- Pointless
- Void(!)
- Dud
- Futile
- Ineffectual
- Impotent (sheesh, that's harsh.)
- Dysfunctional
- Inept
- On-rails(!)
- Linear

Insert other synonyms of useless here.
Take it from an avid RPG player who burnt himself on BioWare, Telltale Games, and other "cinematic, choice driven" "role-playing" "games". Everything in quotes are subject to change whenever asked by players.